# Arch linux - вертикальные полосы при запуске ПК

Tags: linux, archlinux, bios, видеодрайвера

Я новичок в linux, но все же решился поставить Arch. При запуске ПК, на котором стоит Arch linux с графической оболочкой KDE Plasma, на секунду появляются вертикальные, цветные, маленькие полоски не на весь экран. Не могу понять, из-за чего они возникают. Есть предположение, что это так запускаются драйвера на видеокарту. У меня видеокарта GeForce GTX 750 Ti. На Fedora linux такого нет.

Comment: скорее всего необходимо обезвредить nouveau, т.е. запретить, посмотрите в интернете, он как то вносится в черный список, а потом надо поставить nvidia драйвер

Comment: А если сразу при установке arch linux устанавливать не проприетарные драйвера на nvidia? nouveau тоже ставиться? По идеи нет, т.к. она поставляется с проприетарными драйверами. В принципе, у меня эти полоски возникают на долю секунды и сразу исчезают, но все же неприятно.

Comment: Я копался в доках https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) и нашел в 5 пункте в установке это: 5. Перезагрузите систему. Пакет nvidia содержит файл, который добавляет модуль nouveau в чёрный список, поэтому перезагрузка необходима. Так что, скорее всего, если ставить пакеты с сайта, то nouveau должно отключиться, надо проверить.

Comment: Решил проблему. Просто нужно было переустановить Linux с проприетарными драйверами от NVIDIA.